# Android Fragment: Null Pointer Exception on calling setAdapter() for a Snipper

Tags: android, android-fragments, drop-down-menu, android-arrayadapter

I am creating an app using fragments. 
There are three fragments for my main activity inflating from a Bottom Navigation menu. I've added a Dropdown **snipper** in the layout of fragment 1. 
In the main activity I am trying to set the **adapter** for that snipper. The code is following:

```
//In the main activity onCreate()
    snipper1 = findViewById(R.id.spinner_add);
             categories = new String[]{"Phones", "Laptops", "Tablets"};
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, categories);
            snipper1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Because I am not initializing the fragment1 in the activity before calling `snipper.setAdapter()` *& I do not want to do so*, so I am getting the following NullPointer Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

My Alternate question is:

"How can I call `findViewById()` from the **activity** for an element present in its child **fragment**"?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Can you put up a xml file ?

Comment: when are you initializing your fragment ?

Comment: Your spinner is in Fragment and from activity you are trying to find view and attaching adapter. You will always get null.Try using interface for fragment and activity communication.

Answer (score 3):

try this code,

```
Spinner spinner = (your view).findViewById(**your xml spinner view id**);
     List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
     list.add("Phones");
     list.add("Laptops");
     list.add("Tablets");
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>((here if you use Activity use **this** or in fragment use **getContext()**),
         android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);(here put your spinner item xml)
     dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
     spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. In fragment getView().findViewById() is giving error: "unreachable statement"

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**
Directly accessing fragment's views outside fragment is not a good idea. You should use fragment callback interfaces to handle such cases and avoid bugs. The following way works but it is not recommended as it is not a good practice.

You should set your adapter inside the Fragment's callback class:

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add,container,false);
        Snipper snipper1= view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_add);

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);

        return view;
    }
```